# Fragments not showing/hiding like expected

Tags: java, android, hide, show

So I wish to hide a fragment while showing another with the push of a button.  Because of the complexities of my app, I can't use a tabHost here, so I made two buttons that will act as tabs that will show and hide two fragments.  One of the buttons works, but the other button hides the current fragment, but fails to show the other.  Sometime this button waits a second or so and then shows part of the fragment that was just hidden.  Any idea on what's going on?

Here is the code in my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/text_personal_A"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="true"
            android:text="@string/my_account"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_personal_B"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="true"
            android:text="@string/my_messages"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_fragment_A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_fragment_B"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code in my Fragment

```
package com.kofsoft.mobile.fragment;

import com.kofsoft.mobile.R;
import com.kofsoft.mobile.constants.Constants;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PersonalCenterFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    private TextView accountTab, employeeTab;
    AccountInformationFragment accountInfo;
    EmployeeInformationFragment employeeInfo;
    FragmentManager fragMan;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal, container, false);

        accountInfo = new AccountInformationFragment();
        employeeInfo = new EmployeeInformationFragment();
        accountTab = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_personal_A);
        accountTab.setOnClickListener(this);
        employeeTab = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_personal_B);
        employeeTab.setOnClickListener(this);
        fragMan = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
        fragTrans.replace(R.id.dynamic_fragment_A, accountInfo,
 Constants.ACCOUNT_INFO_TAG);       
        fragTrans.replace(R.id.dynamic_fragment_B, employeeInfo,
 Constants.EMPLOYEE_INFO_TAG);
        fragTrans.hide(employeeInfo);   
        fragTrans.commit();

        return v;       
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View tab) {
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
        if(tab.getId() == R.id.text_personal_A){
            fragTrans.hide(employeeInfo);
            fragTrans.show(accountInfo);            
        }else if(tab.getId() == R.id.text_personal_B){  
            fragTrans.hide(accountInfo);
            fragTrans.show(employeeInfo);       
        }
        fragTrans.commit();

    }

}
```

Maybe this has something to do with the fact that I'm using two FrameLayouts in my XML to store my fragments.  I'm not sure, but wasn't able to find anyone else with this particular problem.

Comment: I changed getFragmentManager() to getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() and that hasn't changed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xml is not properly set . If you specify `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for fragment A it will take all the space vertically .then fragment two goes down/out of the screen. you can set it by specifying wrap_content in FragmentA or setting  `android:layout_above="@id/dynamic_fragment_B"` in fragment A.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/text_personal_A"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="true"
            android:text="@string/my_account"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_personal_B"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="true"
            android:text="@string/my_messages"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_fragment_A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/dynamic_fragment_B"
        />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_fragment_B"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change from android:layout_width to android:layout_weight because sometime the first framelayout take up all the available space so you don't see the second one.